# PHP - Get previous month name from current month

Tags: php, date

```
$_POST['month_year'] = APR-2015

$mth = "April";
$pre_mth = Date("F", strtotime($mth . " last month"));
```

`$pre_mth` gives me only month name which is 'March'.

How can I fetch previous month-year in the format `MAR-2015`?

Comment: Is the output format supposed to be fixed or should it match whatever the input format is?

Comment: For the input with format `APR-2015` the output must be `MAR-2015` i.e. same format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function options:

```
$pre_mth = strtoupper(date("M-Y", strtotime($mth . " last month")));
// strtoupper just to uppercase 'Mar' to 'MAR'
```

Comment: I downvoted because I understand OP's question as that the output should be in the **same format as the input** but not necessarily in the fixed format. However, I retracted the vote because I realize it's actually not clear.

Comment: @cascaval: hm, interesting idea, I took the input format as fixed.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: what you want to explain about `last month`? You have that in your question so I thought it's clear to you

Answer (score 3):

```
$input = 'APR-2015';

$dt = new DateTime($input);
$dt->modify('last month');

$output = $dt->format('M-Y');

echo strtoupper($output);

// Output:
// MAR-2015
```

Answer (score 2):

You were missing **'Y'** within your [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$mth="April";
$pre_mth = strtoupper(Date("M-Y", strtotime($mth . " last month")));
echo $pre_mth;// MAR-2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php), i.e:

```
$post = "APR-2015";
echo strtoupper(date('M-Y', strtotime($post. "-1 Month")));
```

---

Output:

```
MAR-2015
```

---

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/njVKd2)